# Conjur quickstart Create myConjurAccount showing rake aborted! OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError:

Tags: docker, openssl, docker-compose, containers, cyber-ark

when i try to create conjure account using the command( I am following conjur quickstart tutorial)

```
docker-compose exec conjur conjurctl account create myConjurAccount > admin_data
```

i am getting Cipher error in admin_data file,
when i `cat admin_data` file

```
rake aborted!
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: 
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/slosilo-2.1.1/lib/slosilo/symmetric.rb:37:in`final'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/slosilo-2.1.1/lib/slosilo/symmetric.rb:37:in `decrypt'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/slosilo-2.1.1/lib/slosilo/attr_encrypted.rb:60:in `decrypt'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/slosilo-2.1.1/lib/slosilo/attr_encrypted.rb:40:in `block (3 levels) in attr_encrypted'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/slosilo-2.1.1/lib/slosilo/adapters/sequel_adapter.rb:32:in `get_key'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/slosilo-2.1.1/lib/slosilo/keystore.rb:18:in `get'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/slosilo-2.1.1/lib/slosilo/keystore.rb:47:in `[]'
/opt/conjur-server/app/models/account.rb:6:in `find_or_create_accounts_resource'
/opt/conjur-server/lib/tasks/account.rake:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => account:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

But sometimes its creating i am not understanding what makes it working in the background. Any help will be appreciated.
and also `docker-compose ps` showing

```
bot_app             tail -F anything                 Up
conjur_client       sleep infinity                   Up
conjur_server       conjurctl server                 Up       80/tcp
nginx_proxy         nginx -g daemon off;             Up       0.0.0.0:8443->443/tcp, 80/tcp
postgres_database   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up       5432/tcp 
openssl             openssl req -newkey rsa:20 ...   Exit 0
```

Everytime openssl exiting with 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by removing all stopped containers before running the conjure docker container using `docker container prune`.